# In Ruby, variable names are not objects. Why?

Tags: ruby

This came up in slide 6 of the [10 Things Every Java Programmer Should Know About Ruby](http://onestepback.org/articles/10things/9everythingisanobject5.html) talk.

Now, I reviewed some answers and the general consensus is that anything with value, not a mere pointer, is an object. I am confused by this. If `a = 1`, `a` would share methods with `1`, and in fact they would have the same `object_id`. How is saying "a is an object" not accurate?

Comment: The slide isn't saying that `a` isn't an object. It is saying that the *name* isn't an object. As you show, the name references an object.

Comment: Subtle but important distinction. Thanks.

Comment: One *could* argue that very very very strictly speaking, variable names *are* objects. Specifically, they are `Symbol`s. *Variables*, however, definitely aren't objects. (Neither are methods, BTW. You can get a proxy object which *represents* the method, but you can't get the method itself.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for mentioning the Symbol class. As I just started learning Ruby, it could have been a long way before I get to meet this class.

Answer (score 4):

What the slide says is correct: Variables are not objects. However, the second statement here — "anything with value, not a mere pointer, is an object" — doesn't even make sense in the context of Ruby, which doesn't have "mere pointers" distinct from "things with value/objects".

The thing is, the variable `a` doesn't share methods with the object `1`. It it certainly not the same thing as `1`, because otherwise if you later wrote `a = 2`, you'd completely obliterate the number 1! The variable is just a place that holds a reference to the object `1`. You can't talk to this place like you could an object — for example, as you noted, variables don't have distinct `object_id`s. The only things you can do with a variable are talk to the object it references and reassign it with a reference to a different object. The variable itself is not an object, it's just a place to store a reference to an object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess it's one of those things that I should get my head around. It's certainly the case in almost all other languages, I just got confused it was mentioned in a talk that compares two languages, which made it seem as one of the things special to Ruby, where in fact it is not.

Comment: @why-el: Yeah, I think the reason he pointed it out is because Ruby's reputation is "Everything is an object," when actually there are a handful of things (such as variables) that are *not* objects.